# Using dataframe.withColumn and a variable does not seem to work

Tags: python, dataframe, databricks

I'm trying to write a statement like the following:
profileId = "some value"
df.withColumn("ProfileId", col(profileId)) and am getting an AnalysisException on DataBricks.  As far as I know, this should be working so I'm wondering what the problem is.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the error ?

here is a description of the withColumn() :
Returns a new DataFrame by adding a column or replacing the existing column that has the same name.
The column expression must be an expression over this DataFrame; attempting to add a column from some other dataframe will raise an error.--




May be you need to try this if its not the same column :

df.withColumn("the_new_column",df["existing_column"]+profield).collect()

Comment: The error message is simply that I got is: AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '`3530273972194849`' given input columns: [defaultBid, campaignId, state, name, adGroupId];;\n'Project [adGroupId#21456L, campaignId#21457L, defaultBid#21458, name#21459, state#21460, '3530273972194849 AS profileId#21466]\n+- Relation[adGroupId#21456L,campaignId#21457L,defaultBid#21458,name#21459,state#21460] json\n".  Are you saying that I can't add a new column from a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `lit` with the variable, eg

```
%py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, expr, when, lit

df = sc.parallelize([
    ("orange", "apple"), ("kiwi", None), (None, "banana"), 
    ("mango", "mango"), (None, None)
]).toDF(["fruit1", "fruit2"])

profileId = "some value"

display(df.withColumn("ProfileId", lit(profileId)))
```

Comment: That is what I finally figured out on my own.  Thanks for the answer though.  It works perfectly.